# Why does Console namespace need to be imported into a Console application project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

If I create a new Console application then this compiles ok:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

An alternative is this:

```
Imports System.Console
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

What I don't *now* understand is, as this is a console application, why aren't these projects created in such a way that the following will compile?:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Put another way: *if it is a Console app why do I need to import the Console namespace?*

Is this the same behavior as when using a `winForms` application I say `Me.someControl`? Although in that situation I can leave of the `Me` and it will still compile without importing a forms namespace.

**EDIT**

```
Imports System.Console
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ReadKey()
        Console.ReadKey()  '<<adding namespace seems a bit pointless as I still need to specify Console
    End Sub

    Function ReadKey() As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

End Module
```

**FURTHER EDIT**

Hans has suggested further behaviour and to replicate this I have the following:

I've added a new `ClassLibrary1` to the same `Solution` like so...

[image]

In the Console `ConsoleSandpit` I've got the following, with a reference to `ClassLibrary1` like so...

[image]

...only problem is I'm expecting a compilation error from the above but it seems to be running ok!

Comment: Put another way: why do *any* namespaces exist? Why not have *all* functions available without any namespaces or prefixes?

Comment: different objects will have different functions available to them, but I suppose these functions might have the same name e.g `ObjectX.functionA` might exist but also `ObjectY.functionA`. But if you are already _inside_ a console application it seems strange that the console has to be explicitly referenced; although I suppose it is similar to saying `Me.X` when inside a `winforms` project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Console` is not a namespace.  `ReadKey` is a shared method in the `Console` class which is in the `System` namespace

So, the breakdown of the following statement is:

```
System.Console.ReadKey()
```

- `System` - Namespace
- `Console` - Class
- `ReadKey` - Shared method

So, when you call `Console.ReadKey()` (without specifying the namespace), you would normally expect to have to import `System` at the top of your code file.  However, that is unnecessary because in VB.NET projects, you can specify a list of default namespaces that are automatically imported for all files in the project.  You can modify these using the check-list of default namespaces in your project properties designer.  `System`, among others, is automatically imported as a default namespace with all of the project templates.

As you demonstrated in your question, it is possible in VB.NET to import a class or module name.  The `Imports` statement is not limited to just working with namespaces.  However, as far as I know, there is no way to import a class name with the default namespaces option for the project (or at least not with the project properties designer, anyway).

If `System.Console` was a namespace, I agree that you'd expect the project template for console projects to import that namespace by default.  However, since it's not a namespace at all, you wouldn't expect it to do that :)

Comment: might have to tick this to push you over 10k !!

Comment: Woohoo!  Finally!  Thanks :)

Comment: did you get one of those congratulation screens with loads of flashing lights and fireworks?

Comment: can you see the **FURTHER EDIT** I added to the OP? Why did that scenario compile? What I'm trying to do in the FURTHER EDIT is replicate a scenario that Hans mentioned in his answer - what was I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce the exact behavior Hans is describing either.  The closest I can come to is if you create the class library with that method and you intend to call THAT method, you can't do so easily if you have an `Imports System.Console` at the top of your file.  Otherwise, it all compiles for me too, so I'm not sure what he's referring to, specifically.

Comment: hey Steve - do you ever Import `System.Console`? or do you just import the namespace `System` and then in your code write `Console.xxx`? More readable to actually include the word Console in your code?

Comment: I never import class names.  I find that confusing.  In fact I find it annoying that module names are always imported by default.  But, as far as what's normal?  I'd say I've never seen anyone import `System.Console`.  Any time I've seen or worked with console project code, the code always precedes all of the calls to `Console` methods with the class' name.

Comment: hey Steve - you ever played around with `VBA`? See [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101997/move-a-commonly-used-class-module-to-a-shared-location-possibly-to-dll)

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately, for me), I don't have any experience with VBA, so I'm sorry to say that I can't be much help to you on that one...

Answer (score 1):

1) You can do plenty of useful things, over many functions, inside a console application, without wanting or needing to actually interact with the `Console`.

2) I could easily envisage wanting to write a function called `ReadKey` which puts out a small prompt for one of two or three keys to be pressed - based on the user input, if its one of those keys, return it. Otherwise, indicate the error and re-prompt. Why should I have to pick a *different* name for this function, because my own namespace has been automatically polluted with the methods from `Console`?

Namespaces exist to help to separate and organize functionality. You're given options (such as the `Imports` statement) to hide these separations, where it makes sense for *you* within *your* application - but I wouldn't want this forced on *all* users.

Comment: ...`imports` doesn't seem to help if I create a function `ReadKey` - I then have to explicitly write `Console.ReadKey` if I want to use the console's readKey function as apposed to my function

Answer (score 1):

Add a class library project to your solution and paste this code:

```
Module FooBar
    Sub ReadKey(ByVal wait As Integer)
    End Sub
End Module
```

And observe how your original code now suddenly fails to compile.  With a seriously obtuse error message as well: "Argument not specified for parameter 'wait'".  You can lose **hours** of your life trying to figure out why Console.ReadKey() wants a *wait* argument.

Comment: +1 suspect I'm not following your instructions correctly Hans as mine seems to still compile - can I edit your post with my attempt at following these instructions - you can then re-edit with correct steps?

Comment: I tested this scenario before posting.  I doubt you'll improve it by editing.

Comment: No Hans - I'm a newbie who is interested in the bevaviour you are telling me about but I'm having problems replicating it - I'll edit my OP with steps I'm going through - maybe you can review them and tell me what I'm doing wrong?